# Method of moments as non-parametric model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, method-of-moments

In Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) about nonparametric statistics there is "Method of moments (statistics) with polynomial probability distributions" listed as non-parametric model.

How does it make sense? How method of estimation parameters can be non-parametric?

Parenthetically, is there any difference between "non-parametric" and "nonparametric"? Which is more common/correct?

Comment: In general, method of moments is not non-parametric. However, things like Generalized Methods of Moments are typically considered semi-parametric and only require a finite partition of the parameter space to be functionally specified. I think what the wiki page is referring to is something like this: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0174573. The idea is that we want to approximate an unknown pdf on some finite interval. We hypothesize a polynomial basis and use some empirical moment matching to make the approximation fit well.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds reasonably